# Wrong timestamp conversion in mysql database

Tags: mysql, timestamp, grafana, unix-timestamp

I'm trying to group timestamps into slots of 15 Minutes. I'm using the following sql statement to retrieve time data from my mysql database.

```
select
  floor(unix_timestamp(timestamp)/(15*60)) as "Time"
from Table;
```

That results in a table looking like this:

| Time |
| --- |
| 1846513 |
| 1846515 |
| ... |

The resulting timestamps are converted in grafana where I want to display certain panels.

When applying the time conversion option (transform > Convert field type > `Field` Time `as` Time)
the timestamps are converted to a different timestamp than they're supposed to. The result looks like this:

| Time |
| --- |
| 1970-01-01 01:30:46.513 |
| 1970-01-01 01:30:46.515 |
| ... |

When only retrieving the timestamps (They come pre converted to datetime) using the following command

```
select
  timestamp as "Time"
from Table;
```

I get a result that looks like this:

| Time |
| --- |
| 2022-08-30 16:16:07 |
| ... |

How can I get the right time conversion?

Any help is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to multiply back the 15*60 after you divide and use FLOOR().

```
15 * 60 * floor(unix_timestamp(timestamp)/(15*60))
```